# Django Channels setup with Django 2.2 and channels 3.03

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I know there are other questions like this but none of those solutions seem to be working.  I added the version numbers of each framework as that might be a factor.  I have the tutorial on channels site (https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/part_2.html) working locally but when I move over to the production server (Apache) it fails with the following error on daphne:

```
2021-01-26 23:26:15,994 ERROR    Exception inside application: No route found for path 'ws/chat/lobby/'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 71, in __call__
    return await application(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/sessions.py", line 47, in __call__
    return await self.inner(dict(scope, cookies=cookies), receive, send)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/sessions.py", line 254, in __call__
    return await self.inner(wrapper.scope, receive, wrapper.send)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/auth.py", line 181, in __call__
    return await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/middleware.py", line 26, in __call__
    return await self.inner(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 168, in __call__
    raise ValueError("No route found for path %r." % path)
ValueError: No route found for path 'ws/chat/lobby/'.
```

my asgi.py file:

```
import os

import django
from channels.routing import get_default_application

# Fetch Django ASGI application early to ensure AppRegistry is populated
# before importing consumers and AuthMiddlewareStack that may import ORM
# models.
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")
django.setup()
application = get_default_application()
```

my settings.py:

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = "myapp.routing.application"
```

my routing.py:

```
from common.routing import websocket_urlpatterns

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # Empty for now (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

my local routing.py:

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try this : `r'^ws/chat/(?P<room_name>[\w.+]+)/'`. And if you are trying to connect it then connect by using `ws://` protocol not by the `http` protocol.